# problem in a shell command

Tags: unix, shell, awk

i am trying the following command  on the command line

```
ps -u `id | cut -f2 -d"=" | cut -f1 -d"("`  -f | grep ppLSN | awk '{print $9}' | awk '{FS="=";print $2}' | grep KLMN | wc -l
```

the value of teh command is returned as `7`.

but when i am putting the same command inside a script abc_sh like below

```
ps -u `id | cut -f2 -d"=" | cut -f1 -d"("`  -f | grep ppLSN | awk '{print $9}' | awk '{FS="=";print $2}' | grep $XYZ | wc -l
```

and i am calling the script on the command line as `abc_sh XYZ=KLMN` and it does not work and returns `0`
the problem is with the grep in the command `grep $XYZ` 
could anybody please tell why this is not working?

Comment: To start with, instead of that unnecessary cutting, use id -u .

Comment: Awful question, why are you hiding relevant information? First it worked before (no mention of that), then you are using ksh, not bash (the usual), and no mention of that either.

Comment: Separating the `-f` argument so far out to the right after the command expansion makes it lost in the clutter. Put it at the beginning: `ps -f -u ...` (I used separate hyphens here purely for, uh, "aesthetics").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your $1 variable (first argument to the script) is set to XYZ=KLMN.

Just use `abc_sh KLMN` and `grep $1` instead of `grep $XYZ`.

(Assuming we are talking about bash here)

The other alternative is defining a temporary environment variable in which case you would have to call it like this: `XYZ=KLMN abc_sh`

EDIT:

Found what you were using, you have to use `set -k` (see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS in the BASH manual)

```
          -k      All arguments in the form of assignment  statements  are
                  placed  in the environment for a command, not just those
                  that precede the command name.
```

So

```
vinko@parrot:~$ more abc
#!/bin/bash
echo $XYZ
vinko@parrot:~$ set -k
vinko@parrot:~$ ./abc XYZ=KLMN
KLMN
vinko@parrot:~$ set +k
vinko@parrot:~$ ./abc XYZ=KLMN

vinko@parrot:~$
```

So, the place where this was working probably has `set -k` in one of the startup scripts (bashrc or profile.)

Comment: There is a constraint that i should not call the script like u said abc_sh KLMN.

Comment: You should have said so, but anyway, the way to do it is answered twice already

Comment: this a an already existing script where it will be called  like that only abc_sh XYZ=KLMN and now i am using this variable  XYZ.but this is not working .even if i do echo $XYZ before the command inside the script it does not show anything.and this variable is already used some other places in the script already where it is working fine.

Comment: did you do "XYZ=KLMN abc_sh" instead of "abc_sh XYZ=KLMN"?

Comment: why don't you paste the original script as well? Are you using BASH?

Comment: @vinko thanks a lot for ur suggestion of using set -k.it has solved the problem:)

Answer (score 2):

Try any of these to set a temporary environment variable:

```
XYZ=KLMN abc_sh
env XYZ=KLMN abc_sh
(export XYZ=KLMN; abc_sh)
```

Comment: Dysoistia :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386824/hired-as-a-developer-to-maintain-and-update-current-code-base-no-docs/1386842#1386842

Answer (score 1):

you are using so many commands chained together....

```
ps -u `id -u` -f |  awk -v x="$XYZ" -v p="ppLSN" '$0~p{
 m=split($9,a,"=")
 if(a[2]~x){count++} 
}
END{print count}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
ps -u $(id -u) -o args | grep $XYZ | cut -f2- -d " "
```

Like this:

```
XYZ=KLMN abc_sh
```