# Problem in running a script

Tags: bash, unix, shell, ksh

i have unix shell script which is need to be run like below

```
test_sh XYZ=KLMN
```

the content of the script is

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo $XYZ
```

for using the value of XYZ i have do `set -k` before i run the script.

is there a way where i can do  this without doint set -k before running the script. or is there something that i can do in the script where i can use value of the parameter given while running the script in the below way

```
test_sh XYZ=KLMN
```

i am using ksh.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You received good answers for your homework here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570383/problem-in-a-shell-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use the environment variable "INSTANCE" in your script.

For that, the environment variable must be set in advance of executing your script.  Using the "set" command sets exportable environment variables.  Incidentally, my version of ksh dates from 1993 and the "-k" option was obsolete back then.

To set an environment variable so that it is exported into spawned shells, simply use the "export" command like so:

```
export INSTANCE='whatever you want to put here'
```

If you want to use a positional parameter for your script -- that is have the "KLMN" value accessed within your script, and assuming it is the first parameter, then you do the following in your script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo $1
```

You can also assign the positional parameter to a local variable for later use in your script like so:

```
#!/bin/ksh

param_one=$1
echo $param_one
```

You can call this with:

```
test_sh KLMN
```

Note that the spacing in the assignment is important -- do not use spaces.

Answer (score 4):

How about running this?

```
XYZ=KLMN ./test_sh //running from directory where test_sh is
```

Comment: synonym for using the external /usr/bin/env, which is shell neutral: env XYZ=KLMN ./test.sh

Comment: contraint is i have to run the script in this way only test_sh XYZ=KLMN

Answer (score 3):

If your script needs no other arguments, a quick and dirty way do to it is to put

```
eval "$@"
```

at the start of your script. This will evaluate the command line arguments as shell commands. If those commands are to assign a shell/environment variable, then that's what it will do.

It's quick-and-dirty since anything could be put on the command line, causing problems from a syntax error to a bad security hole (if the script is trusted).

I'm not sure if "$@" means the same in ksh as it does in bash - using just $* (without quotes) would work too, but is even dirtier.

Answer (score 0):

I am tring this option

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo $1
awk '{FS="=";print $2}' $1
```

and on the command line

```
test_sh INSTANCE=LSN_MUM
```

but awk is failing.is there any problem over here?

Comment: That's treating `$1` as a file name. You should echo it through a pipe to awk instead.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `#!/bin/ksh -k` will work (untested).